# Signal R client not raising On even with Json serialized complex objects

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, .net-5

I am trying to implement signal r client and server with json serialization.
Currently I am targeting .NET 5 and use Microsoft json serializer implementation.
My messages are represented by complex objects and there is an **JsonConverter** used for reading and writing.
What I see is that on the client the On event is never raised except if handler parameter specified as an object class.

```
        connection.On("EntityEventAsync", (object obj) => 
        {
            //obj will be json object here
        });
```

On client side I can clearly see that the messages are received as JsonConverter is called and reads the messages as it should BUT the On event is never raised.

**Typed client hub code**

```
public interface IEventsClient
{
    Task EntityEventAsync(DetailedMessage message);
}


[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Basic,Bearer")]
public class EventHub : Hub<Clients.IEventsClient>
{   
    #region CONSTRUCTOR
    public EventHub()
    {
    }
    #endregion
}
```

What I can be missing here?

Comment: Hi @NullRerence,Could you please share your hub method?

Comment: @Rena I have updated the question with hub code.

Answer (score 0):

If some one else struggles with same problem then it be might the problem with the JsonConverter implementation as it in my case.

Its possible to enable Signal R client logging as mentioned here [`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0`](http://%60https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0%60) and that should make it easier to figure out the problem.